# How to create a loop to replace values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables something like this:

```
Table 1:
+---------------------+
| name_fr |  name_en  |
+---------------------+
| valfr1  |  valen1   |
+---------------------+


Table 2:
+------------------------+
| id |      value        |
+------------------------+
| 1  |  valfr1 is thiss  |
+------------------------+
| 2  | something random  |
+------------------------+
```

I try to loop each row of table 1 and take the values of each field, then for each row in table 2 I intend to do a replacement in the value field. Given the tables example, the loop would do something like this:

```
update table2 set value = replace(value, 'valfr1', 'valen1');
```

And it would replace the value in table2 with id 1 and it will have 'valen1 is thiss'

But imagine table1 has for example 100 rows, how can i loop for each of them and try to replace the value?

Thanks for the help, sorry if i couldn't explain myself correctly

Comment: *imagine table1 has for example 100 rows, how can i loop for each of them and try to replace the value?* In recursive CTE (if your server version allows) or in iterative stored procedure.

Comment: PS. You must understand that in theory the final data state may depend on the order of replacement applying.

Comment: I don't think you need loops, but a cross join between the two tables in the update statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Introduction

You can easily achieve something like this with an `update` command. Don't worry, that's ultimately does a loop under the hood, it's just a looping that has been ever optimizing for decades, so it's probable that your loop will not perform as well as that. At least not without a very large amount of effort. So, for this answer I will assume that an `update` is good-enough for this purpose.

Reference: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/

## The query

```
UPDATE TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2
ON TABLE1.value LIKE CONCAT('%', TABLE2.name_fr, '%')
SET TABLE1.value = REPLACE(TABLE1.value, TABLE2.name_fr, TABLE2.name_en);
```

## Explanation

This query matches all records from `TABLE1` to their counterparts from `TABLE2`, where `TABLE1.value` contains `TABLE2.name_fr`. For these matches the replacement is done for `TABLE1.value` accordingly to the mapping specified in `TABLE2`.

## Edge-case

If there is a `name_fr` value which contains another, then it is better to evaluate the former first, because the latter could make premature replacements if evaluated first. For this purpose you could order `TABLE2` descendingly by `fr_name` length and alias is to some name.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what  i needed. Thanks for the detailed info also!

Comment: I have a question regarding your answer, if a value of table 2 have multiple occurences of name_fr in the string, how can I replace all of them? From the above answer only first is substitued. I've looked up and seen nested replace() calls for this, but can this be done while having a key => value replacement table as in my case?